# reload a .sql schema without restarting mysqld

Tags: sql, mysql, schema

Is it possible to reload a schema file without having to restart mysqld?  I am working in just one db in a sea of many and would like to have my changes refreshed without doing a cold-restart.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "reload a schema file", I assume you're referring to a file that has all the `SQL` statements defining your database schema? i.e. creating `tables`, `views`, `stored procecures`, etc.?

The solution is fairly simple - keep a file with all the `SQL` that creates the `tables`, etc. in a file, and before all the `CREATE` statements, add a `DELETE/DROP` statement to remove what's already there. Then when you want to do a reload, just do:

```
cat myschemafile.sql | mysql -u userid -p databasename
```

Comment: Yes, schema changes are instantaneous